# How to implement multiple @MappedSuperClass inheritence for entities

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm setting up JPA domain models with Eclipselink. I have built these models with multiple @MappedSuperclass classes before getting to the actual @Entity class. When I execute criteria queries, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: The attribute [null] is not present in the managed type [EntityTypeImpl@2123492724:DogEntity [ javaType: class com.fake.fake.entity.DogEntity descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.fake.fake.entity.DogEntity --> [DatabaseTable(Dog)]), mappings: 22]].;
```

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractBaseEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    protected String id;

    @Column(name = "lastUpdated")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    protected Date lastUpdated;
}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class PetImpl extends AbstractBaseEntity implements Pet {
    // I pretty much use this class to implement some of Pet
    // and add some shared transient fields

    @Transient
    protected List<String> tags;

    @Override
    public List<String> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    // I have some abstract methods in here also
    public abstract int getMaxTags();
}

@Entity
public class DogEntity extends PetImpl {

    @Column(name = "breed")
    private String breed;

    @Override
    public int getMaxTags() {
        return 1;
    }

}
```

Full Stacktrace (apologies if confusing, tried to strip of enterprise-specific terms)

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: The attribute [null] is not present in the managed type [EntityTypeImpl@909914828:DogEntity [ javaType: class com.fake.fake.entity.DogEntity descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.fake.fake.entity.DogEntity --> [DatabaseTable(Dog)]), mappings: 22]].; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The attribute [null] is not present in the managed type [EntityTypeImpl@909914828:DogEntity [ javaType: class com.fake.fake.entity.DogEntity descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.fake.fake.entity.DogEntity --> [DatabaseTable(Dog)]), mappings: 22]].
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:384) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:418) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
```

I would expect that having having @MappedSuperclass on each of my super classes would be fine, but there seems to be some issue that I can't really diagnose since its just saying I have some attribute [null].

Comment: This confuses a bit `abstract class Pet ... implements Pet`

Comment: Add fullstack trace

Comment: Sorry @pirho , fixed now.

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos added

Comment: Other than that are entities being loaded? those without `@MappedSuperclass`?